# SCons StaticLibrary not rebuilt after header change

Tags: c++, c, scons

In this example, foo.c includes foo.h.
When foo.h is changed, foo.c is rebuild to foo.o, but libfoobar.a is not.

```
Import('env')

penv = env.Clone()
penv.Append(CPPPATH=['./'])

penv.StaticLibrary('foobar',[
        'foo.c',
        'bar.c',
    ],
)
```

Any hints?

Comment: How do you know it was not rebuilt? What was the change in the header file? If a rebuilt object file didn't change (md5), there's no need for the archive to be rebuilt.

Comment: Oh right! You are right! Didn't know dependency worked with sums! That's nice, thanks! If you find an answer suitable, please feel free.

Comment: How about the down voter share his thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SCons, a *decider* is what determines if a target needs to be rebuilt. The default decider is MD5. This means that even if an object file is re-built, if its MD5 doesn't change, then nothing that includes / links against that object needs rebuilt.  This is in contrast to Make, which uses filesystem timestamps to decide whether or not to rebuild a target.

So, if your header file change was whitespace or otherwise insignificant, nothing above the object file in the dependency tree needs rebuilt.